# How to change a material in Unity using a script on collison

Tags: unity-game-engine, collider

I am currently making a mobile game in Unity3D. I want it so that when a ball with the tag 'Damage' is collided with, it will change the material of a damage indicator at the top of the screen. Is there an easy way to do this?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would typically put something like "damage indicator" in your "GameManager" and a GameManager is usually a singleton. It means you on time of collision, you can check the collider tag, if it's "Damage" then you call a function in your GameManager to change the material of your "damage indicator". Something like this:

```
public class ExampleClass : MonoBehaviour
{

    ....

    void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Damage")
            GameManager.instance.DamageDone();
    }
}
```

GameManager:

```
public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static GameManager instance;

    public Material damageMat;
    public Renderer damageIndicatorRenderer;

    ....

    void DamageDone()
    {
        damageIndicatorRenderer.material = damageMat;
    }
}
```